# zend framework can't find Model classes?

Tags: zend-framework, model

Yall:

I have a simple question, it might be a simple configuration issue, but
I have a Model defined, and when I try to access it from a controller it
fails.

The Model is in the model directory, and when I look at the quickstart app,
it seems like this should work.

Here is my model:

```
<?php
class Application_Model_User  { 
    protected $_user;
    protected $_password;
    protected $_userId; // very simple right
}
?>
```

My controller just stops.. here is the controller code:

```
<?php
class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {     
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        // display login form
        $users = new Application_Model_User();
        echo "test never echos.. stopped above ? weird huh.."; // fails before ..
    }
?>
```

Thank you everyone,

Comment: is the directory named `model` or `models` its assumed by the resource loader to use `models` - plural. What do your error logs say?

Comment: Controllers don't just stop. Make sure you have error reporting enabled.

Comment: The directory is named models, and here is the error..

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application_Model_User' not found in C:\....\UserController.php on line 13

.. clearly I'm a newbie to Zend, but I created the project from the zf commandline.. Do I still have to tweak the bootstrap, I thought it would automatically be configured to look in /models

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `application.ini`

```
appnamespace = "Application_"
```

App structure:

```
/application/
            /models/
                   /User.php
```

Class definition:

```
class Application_Model_User {}
```

Should work OK.

Comment: Wow.. that worked.. much thanks.. !! 

Thank you StackOverFlow and takeshin