# Problem with model loading in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, model

I have weird problem with zend framework basics. I have simple action in IndexController:

```
public function updateusersAction() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    new Application_Model_Users();
}
```

And a model I want to create is defined in application/models/Users.php (folders generated by zf.bat). The whole body of this file is as follow:

```
<?php

class Application_Model_Users {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

If it matters I use zf 1.10.6 on Windows 7 with xampp. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

ps. I have to make it working on Windows as the target app will have to use COM components...

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: It said it couldn't find the class I called in controller. However it's already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh. Found solution in another thread: [zend framework can't find Model classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509637/zend-framework-cant-find-model-classes)
Anyway, thanks for interest everyone.